# Ansible: Convert a comma- or space-delimited sting to dictionary

Tags: ansible

Ansible v2.9

I want to create a CSR file with alternative names option, so I'm mimicing this example from [openssl_csr – Generate OpenSSL Certificate Signing Request (CSR)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/openssl_csr_module.html)

```
# Create a CSR using above private key
- name: Generate an OpenSSL CSR with subjectAltName extension with dynamic list
  openssl_csr:
    path: "{{ csr_path }}"
    privatekey_path: "{{ key_path }}"
    common_name: "{{ common_name }}"
    subject_alt_name: "{{ item.value | map('regex_replace', '^', 'DNS:') | list }}"
  with_dict:
    dns_servers:
    - my.example.com
    - us.example.com
```

However, I want/need to pass in the `dns_servers` dictionary as either a comma- or space-delimited string that I'll get from a Jenkins text box. So the command line will look like

```
$ ansible-playbook ... -e alt_servers="my.example.com, us.example.com"
```

So I essentially want/need to, in **pseudo-code**

```
dns_servers: "{{ alt_server }}".split(",")
```

and then do

```
# Create a CSR using above private key
- name: Generate an OpenSSL CSR with subjectAltName extension with dynamic list
  openssl_csr:
    path: "{{ csr_path }}"
    privatekey_path: "{{ key_path }}"
    common_name: "{{ common_name }}"
    subject_alt_name: "{{ item.value | map('regex_replace', '^', 'DNS:') | list }}"
  with_dict: "{{ dns_servers }}"
```

Two questions:

1. How can I convert the passed-in string to a dictionary?
2. How can I use the dictionary with the `with_dict` option? Do I have it correct?

Comment: I'm not clear why you want a dictionary. Why not a list?

Comment: @larsks, like i said, I'm just following the example. If you can post an answer with a list, and it works, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to create a single CSR with multiple subjectAlternativeNames. I would probably do something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    csr_path: example.csr
    key_path: example.key
    common_name: example.com
    dns_servers:
      - my.example.com
      - us.example.com

  tasks:
    - name: Generate an OpenSSL CSR with subjectAltName extension with dynamic list
      openssl_csr:
        path: "{{ csr_path }}"
        privatekey_path: "{{ key_path }}"
        common_name: "{{ common_name }}"
        subject_alt_name: "{{ (dns_servers | map('regex_replace', '^', 'DNS:')) | join(',') }}"
```

Here, `dns_servers` is just another variable, like `csr_path` or `common_name`. It's a list, so it's easy to filter with `map` and then create a common-delimited string using `join`.

I've included the variables here in the playbook as an example, but in practice I would probably have these in `group_vars` or something similar.

---

If you're getting the value for `dns_servers` as a string passed in from somewhere else, just use the `split` method to turn it into a list.  Replace `dns_servers` in the `vars` section above with:

```
    dns_servers: "{{ alt_servers.split(',') }}"
```

Now you can call this playbook with `-e alt_servers=my.example.com,us.example.com`.

---

Re: your recent comments; this exact playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    csr_path: example.csr
    key_path: example.key
    common_name: example.com
    dns_servers: "{{ alt_servers.replace(' ', '').split(',') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Generate an OpenSSL CSR with subjectAltName extension with dynamic list
      openssl_csr:
        path: "{{ csr_path }}"
        privatekey_path: "{{ key_path }}"
        common_name: "{{ common_name }}"
        subject_alt_name: "{{ (dns_servers | map('regex_replace', '^', 'DNS:')) | join(',') }}"
```

With this command line works without errors:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml  -e alt_servers="'us.example.com, my.example.com'"
```

And the reuslting CSR looks correct:

```
$ openssl req -in example.csr -noout -text
[...]
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:us.example.com, DNS:my.example.com
[...]
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you carefully read my OP, `dns_server` is a dynamic variable, whose value is set by a Jenkins user by filling in URLs in a text box. You're hard-coding it. You answered my question #2.

Comment: Nice! It works. However if I can break it by passing `-e alt_servers="my.example.com, us.example.com"` that is, I put a space after the comma. I tried `dns_servers: "{{ (alt_servers | replace(' ', '')).split(',') }}"` to no avail.

Comment: Hmm, I guess having a space there, after the comma, is invalid syntax?

Comment: If you want to include a space in the value on the command line, you need double quoting: `-e alt_servers='"my.example.com, us.example.com"'`. This is an artifact of how Ansible parses values.

Comment: Per my previous comment, that's EXACTLY what I did, put a " " around the parameters, but it still failed.

Comment: Works for me. My latest update includes the exact playbook and command line I'm using.

Comment: Oops, I missed the single-quote. Yeah it works! Thanks a LOT!